# Phaser 3 attack animation stuck at first frame when i press the button

Tags: frame, phaser-framework, phaserjs

Hello we are using Phaser 3 and Parcel to make a game for an university project. We have run into a problem while creating the attack animation of the player character.

So whats suppoused to happen is that when the X key is pressed the attack animation plays and thats it but instead what happens is that it gets stuck at the first frame of the animation, it may be because when the velocity is 0 another animation plays at the same times and pressing the x key sets the velocity to 0, but we dont know how to change that so it works correctly.

This is the code for the character, it is a component that we call into another scene:

```js
import Phaser from "phaser";
import Enemies from "../components/Enemies";
import Hitbox from "../components/Hitbox";

export default class Player extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
  constructor(scene, x, y, texture, velocity) {
    super(scene, x, y, texture);
    this.setTexture("C4");

    scene.add.existing(this);
    scene.physics.add.existing(this);
    this.scene = scene;
    this.body.allowGravity = false;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.cursor = scene.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    this.xKey = scene.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.X);

    this.KeySave = null;
    this.facingDirection = null;
    this.damageAmount = 100;

  }

  update() {

    this.body.setVelocity(0);

    if (this.cursor.left.isDown) {
      this.body.setVelocityX(-this.velocity);
      this.anims.play("walkingLeft", true);
      this.KeySave = "left";

    } else if (this.cursor.right.isDown) {
      this.body.setVelocityX(this.velocity);
      this.anims.play("walkingRight", true);
      this.KeySave = "right";

    } else if (this.cursor.up.isDown) {
      this.body.setVelocityY(-this.velocity);
      this.anims.play("walkingUp", true);
      this.KeySave = "up";

    } else if (this.cursor.down.isDown) {
      this.body.setVelocityY(this.velocity);
      this.anims.play("walkingDown", true);
      this.KeySave = "down";
    }

    if (this.KeySave !== null) {
      this.facingDirection = this.KeySave;
    }

    if (this.body.velocity.x === 0 && this.body.velocity.y === 0) {
      switch (this.facingDirection) {
        case "left":
          this.anims.play("leftStop");
          break;
        case "right":
          this.anims.play("rightStop");
          break;
        case "up":
          this.anims.play("upStop");
          break;
        case "down":
          this.anims.play("downStop");
          break;
        default:
          this.anims.play("downStop");
      }
    }

    if (this.xKey.isDown) {
      switch (this.facingDirection) {
        case "left":
          this.anims.play("AttackLeft");
          this.body.setVelocity(0);
          break;
        case "right":
          this.anims.play("AttackRight");
          this.body.setVelocity(0);
          break;
        case "up":
          this.anims.play("AttackUp");
          this.body.setVelocity(0);
          break;
        case "down":
          this.anims.play("AttackDown");
          this.body.setVelocity(0);
          break;
        default:
          this.anims.play("AttackDown");
          this.body.setVelocity(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make it so that after you press the x key and the animation finishes playing the x key is considered to be up even though you are still pressing it?

Thanks to anyone who responds.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue should be this line

```js
 if (this.body.velocity.x === 0 && this.body.velocity.y === 0) { ... }
```

Here you are always setting the animation to something else. You would have to rearange your `if/else` blocks changing to somethink link this:

```js
if (this.xKey.isDown) {
      // ...
} else if (this.body.velocity.x === 0 && this.body.velocity.y === 0) {
      // ...
}
```

or simply adding a further check like this:

```js
// so only execute when you are not attacking
if (!this.xKey.isDown && this.body.velocity.x === 0 && this.body.velocity.y === 0)
```

> **btw.:** in both cases moving and attacking would be okay, if you want to prevent that you would have to move the `if` - ***this.xKey.isDown*** into to `if`  - ***this.body.velocity.x*** - block.

**alternative like this:**

```js
if (this.body.velocity.x === 0 && this.body.velocity.y === 0) {
    if (this.xKey.isDown) {
      // attacking animations 
    } else {
      // not moving animations 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly it i didn't work, im guessing its because it immediately defaults to the stopped animation after pressing the button, but yeah i dont really know how to fix it

Comment: The simples solution is updating this `if (this.body.velocity.x === 0 && this.body.velocity.y === 0)` **if` clause** to this `if (!this.xKey.isDown && this.body.velocity.x === 0 && this.body.velocity.y === 0)`. This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the other answer we haver already found a solution but thank you a lot either way. In the end we used Player states making it if you attack the player state changes to attacking and if you are not, it changes to idle. Thanks you were of help